# How to store preference in HTML5/Jquery and Cordova/PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

We develop mobile app utilising  HTML5/JQuery and Cordova/PhoneGap.

We have an HTML page for handling "site preference" ie Australia, India, Pakistan etc etc. We would like to store that (per device basis). What is the best way to store this? We know that HTML5 has "localstorage" but doesn't mean the life of this data is only stored when the webkit application running. So if the application is off means that the device will lost the information that being stored. Is that right?

We want to have a simple like Cookies concept in the browser that we can just drop and read from there. But obviosually won't work if we ported to Cordova/PhoneGap. Any ideas how to store this?

Thanks

Comment: localStorage will store key-values permanently until it's explicitly emptied somehow. So, you're safe to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to store simple preferences using [LocalStorage W3C API](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/), All values will be stored on per-device basis and that API is very easy to work with.

```
function getCountry() {
   var currentCountry = window.localStorage.getItem('country');
   return currentCountry;
}

function setCountry(country) {
   window.localStorage.setItem('country', country);
}
```

If you need storing structured data, you could look at the [other storage options](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) which are supported by the Cordova